# Flutter automation test for web apps

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests

i am new dart and flutter. My question is how to write automation test for flutter web projects?
Classic automation tests need to locate ui elements(html). Hovewer flutter does not let it. How can i do that in flutter web apps?

If my flutter app is hosted somewhere, and I want to do end-to-end testing. (Locating and clicking/interacting with elements on the page) is there a testing framework or driver that can work nicely with the shadow dom / setup that flutter creates?

Answer (score 0):

Please use appium-flutter-driver instead of flutter-driver to automate flutter web pages. Since appium-flutter-driver supports hybrid, native, and web applications,

This link should be helpful: https://github.com/appium-userland/appium-flutter-driver

Recently, we've written our flutter web page automation test using appium-flutter-driver.